# .NET 5 WebAPI doesn't serialize date to ISO 8601 format

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I am using .NET 5 and have a simple GET request which includes a date in the return value. This is called by a fetch request from a web page. Here is the date (EndDate):

[image]

My problem is that I am expecting this to be in ISO 8601 format when I receive it as JSON but its returning a different format:

[image]

From what I understand, System.Text.Json serializes to ISO 8601 by default and from what I remember, it was returning the correct format maybe a couple of days ago. But now, its returning a different format without any code changes regarding that (no Converters).

What could be the reason why its behaving this way?

**EDIT AS REQUESTED:**

First the model returned:

[image]

The WebAPI method with the date value:

[image]

The fetch:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support).  And an only description will not help us to assume what actual thing you are trying and what causes the issue. 
Could you please share what you have tried already?
 We could help you check your sample code and based on that we could try to provide suggestions that might help you to fix your issue.

Comment: There's nothing that demonstrates an actual problem here. No code and definitely no actual API results, only screenshots from IDEs or debuggers. Not the actual JSON. Even after the change mentioned in the answer, I can't reproduce any problem

Answer (score -1):

I found what the problem was. I changed the DateTime to be a nullable DateTime and even though the DateTime has a value, it serialized to a different format. Why, I am not sure but the solution I did was to create a converter and added it to the JSON serialization options.

**EDIT:**

According to comments, it doesn't happen for them on a simple project so I am NOT gonna mark this as the answer in case that the solution that worked for me is specific to my project, but will still leave this here in case it works for others.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't due to another bug in the application? You didn't post any code that shows otherwise. This is an `extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence` situation. Besides, .NET 5 is already out of support. It was a single-year "current" version. Even if it had such a bug and nobody caught out of millions of .NET Developers, it would only matter if that bug remained in .NET 6, the Long-Term-Support version. The fix would be to migrate to .NET 6, which is supported until 2024

Comment: No repro. When I create a new WebApi project and change `DateTime` to `DateTime?` in the WeatherForecast class (`public DateTime? Date { get; set; }`), I still get ISO8601 dates: `[{"date":"2022-07-27T13:25:58.4941268+03:00","temperatureC":29,"temperatureF":84,"summary":"Scorching"}`

Comment: Where did the second screenshot come from? That's not a JSON string. It looks like a debug view. Are you sure you weren't seeing a proper `Date()` formatted by that other debugger? Did you try calling the API from a browser and inspecting the response in the Network tab?

Comment: Can't help you with an explanation. That's what I literally did: removed the question mark and it resolved my issue. The screenshot of the object above changed format. Regarding the 2nd screenshot: go to your browser, do a REST API call with a JSON return value and go to the debug menu and hover to the JSON response.

Comment: Post your actual code, actual results. You haven't posted anything usable. I did what you claim and no repro

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to as I've resolved it and explained how I resolved it. You guys can flag this question however you want.

Comment: `go to the debug menu` that's the debugger, not the network tab. At that point you see the *deserialized response*. If you *your JavaScript code* deserialized `endDate` as a `Date` you'll see a formatted version of that Date object. Just as you see `16/07/2022...` in Visual Studio's watch variables.

Comment: You broke your code, not resolve it. This makes this a dangerous answer

Comment: Besides, at 10K you know very well what an MCVE is, and what `actual results` mean.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I am at 10K because I have a question that people keep upvoting. Yes, I do know what MCVE stands for but as I mentioned earlier, I've resolved my problem so I did not feel inclined to create one anymore. Anyway, I don't know what happened but on my current project, that's literally what I did, made it not nullable. I know you were trying to help so as you've requested, I will post in an EDIT shortly the relevant parts of the code in the project where I am able to consistently reproduce the bug, if you still want to see it.